# Versioning for OneDrive Personal (Free) on non-Office files?

Tags: windows, onedrive

I noticed Dropbox (Free version) has the ability to go back to previous versions of any file.  In OneDrive (Free version - not Business), you can go back to previous versions, but it seems to be limited to just Office documents.  Is that the way it is or am I missing a setting to enable versioning for all my file types?  If this doesn't exist for OD Free, does it exist in OD Business?  Are there plans to implement this for OD Free?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your observations are correct - history is currently only available for Office documents. While we can't comment on future plans, I can say that we've definitely heard this feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I think it is most people's expectation that OneDrive free should at least do what Dropbox free can do :)